# Changing rows positions with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is my dataframe:

```
mydf<-structure(list(DS_FAIXA_ETARIA = c("100 anos ou mais", "16 anos", 
"17 anos", "18 anos", "19 anos", "20 anos", "21 a 24 anos", "25 a 29 anos", 
"30 a 34 anos", "35 a 39 anos", "40 a 44 anos", "45 a 49 anos", 
"50 a 54 anos", "55 a 59 anos", "60 a 64 anos", "65 a 69 anos", 
"70 a 74 anos", "75 a 79 anos", "80 a 84 anos", "85 a 89 anos", 
"90 a 94 anos", "95 a 99 anos", "Inválido"), n = c(12130L, 48253L, 
67401L, 79398L, 88233L, 90738L, 149634L, 198848L, 238406L, 265509L, 
297319L, 335263L, 340838L, 331741L, 306299L, 269700L, 234918L, 
198834L, 166733L, 133357L, 84171L, 29421L, 5202L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), groups = structure(list(DS_FAIXA_ETARIA = c("100 anos ou mais", 
"16 anos", "17 anos", "18 anos", "19 anos", "20 anos", "21 a 24 anos", 
"25 a 29 anos", "30 a 34 anos", "35 a 39 anos", "40 a 44 anos", 
"45 a 49 anos", "50 a 54 anos", "55 a 59 anos", "60 a 64 anos", 
"65 a 69 anos", "70 a 74 anos", "75 a 79 anos", "80 a 84 anos", 
"85 a 89 anos", "90 a 94 anos", "95 a 99 anos", "Inválido"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to know if there is something like this using dplytr package: `mydf[c(23,2:22,1),]`

In other word I want to change first and last row position, but using dplyr/tidyr functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `slice` to rearrange the rows as well as subsetting.  The input data is grouped, so it should be `ungroup`ed before doing the `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
     slice(c(n(), 2:(n()-1), 1))
```

Comment: What if the data is'n't grouped?

Comment: @Laura if it is not grouped, then directly apply `slice` i.e. `mydf %>% slice(c(n(), 2:(n()-1), 1))`

Comment: Thanks again @akrun. I am reading now the dplyr pdf. Its much more clear for me now. Many thanks!!

Comment: @Laura with group by, when you do `slice`, it does the slicing for each group